# where is the flex library file exist swc

Tags: apache-flex

can any one help me that where is the SWC or run time library for the flex controls exist in the system?

Or can we provide our own library by using the controls in the dir

C:\Program Files\Adobe\flex_sdk_3.2\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very obvious what are you trying to ask but I'll try to guess :)

So the SWC with Flex controls is located here `{Flex.SDK.root}/frameworks/libs/framework.swc` and the corresponding RSLs are located here `{Flex.SDK.root}/frameworks/rsls`.

What about providing your own library to replace Flex controls I think it is not the right way. The best practice is not modify Flex SDK installation to have possibility to build your project on every computer with different environments (on a different developers computers or on client site).

And you should take in mind there are 4 standard ways to use code in Flash application:

1. Compile your code into SWF.
2. Use Runtime Shared Library aka RSL (which is SWF too).
3. Use SWZ which is signed and can be cached by Flash Player.
4. Use modules which are SWFs.

None of these ways doesn't suppose using Flex SDK in runtime. Flex SDK is being used only in process of building of your application.

So the best way to use some custom controls is to build them with your application using one of the ways I described above (excluding SWZ's which can be produced only by Adobe).

Just leave Flex SDK installation without changes and place classes/SWCs with custom controls in your project's classpath.

Hope this helps.